# Charging Phone with a Modified Power Supply

Tags: power-supply, battery-charging, amperage

I have converted a computer power supply into bench top power supply and I am now ready to add some USB ports to charge various devices. On the power supply label it shows the 5v rail is capable of delivering 14 amps. If I connect a USB port to the 5v rail, will it fry my phone? (I'm assuming 14 amps will most definitely destroy my phone).

I know generally devices will only draw what current they need, but I ask because my phone obviously charges faster with a 2amp charging block vs a 1amp charging block. So therefore, if the power supply can produce 14 amps, wouldn't my phone attempt to charge at 14 amps?

Sorry in advance if this is a noob question, I have only recently started messing with electronics, or anything with electricity for that matter.

Comment: Duplicate of the canonical power supply current question

Comment: *Sorry in advance if this is a noob question* Then un-noob yourself, stroll around on this site and see what similar questions have been asked and answered already.

Comment: A search on here for "charge phone" gives lots of relevant results, also search for "modified power supply" is another.